# Error while running Flume agent

Tags: apache, flume

I m using flume1.4.0 with hbase0.94.10 and hadoop1.1.2....I m new to flume.while i m running an flume agent, i got following error..

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM The size of the object heap + VM data   exceeds the maximum representable size org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file=/usr/local/flume/conf/flume.conf --name agent
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: occurred
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: occurred
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: occurred. Program will exit.
```

**my agent configuration is as follows:**

```
agent1.sources = tail
agent1.channels = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks = sink1
agent1.sources.tail.type = exec
agent1.sources.tail.command = tail -f  /usr/local/jarsfortest/LogsForTest/generatingLogs-app.logs
agent1.sources.tail.channels = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks.sink1.table = testFlume
agent1.sinks.sink1.columnFamily = log
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regex = [a-zA-Zo-9]*[^C][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^C][a-zA-Z0-9]*
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.regexIgnoreCase = true
agent1.sinks.sink1.serializer.colNames = id, no_fill_reason, bid
agent1.sinks.sink1.channel = memoryChannel
agent1.sinks.sink1.type = logger
agent1.channels.memoryChannel.type = memory
agent1.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100
```

Please Help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you have a JVM problem rather than a Flume problem. I'd check that the JAR files are not corrupt, that you haven't set max heap size too small, etc.

Whatever is on the end of this truncated message is probably a clue, `the size of the object heap + VM data`

### Update

`agent1.channels.memoryChannel.capacity = 100`

That capacity looks very small. I'd remove that line and let it use the default.

Comment: Thanks @Sarge. It was due to specifying heap size in hbase configurations.but now flume is running..

Comment: But agent is unable to insert log file data into hbase..
it is showing log file data on consol.

Comment: It may be the very small memory channel capacity.

Comment: BTW the exec source with tail -f is not very reliable. I'd recommended the spooling source.

Comment: Thanks @Sarge.Now it is running well.

Comment: I need just real time data,For that I m using tail but as u r saying it is not reliable so I want to know that spooling source will be right to fulfill my requirement.